# Print all numbers between 1 and 1000 of which the digits' sum is divisble by 8

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write an efficient function that will print all numbers between 1 and 1000 of which the sum of their digits is divisible by 8.

I'm using this `for`:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
```

but not sure about the mathematics.

Comment: What do you mean by figures? Do you mean their digits? So, for example, would number 503 qualify because 5 + 0 + 3 = 8 is divisible by 8?

Comment: title says you want the sum to be divisible by 8, then in your main content you want it divisible by 10. Which one do u want?

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mcve] of your efforts so far.

Comment: You should 1st work over the math, https://math.stackexchange.com/ this site might be helpful to you, then come back and try coding and when you face problems in code then post it here

Comment: yes, their digits. Sorry, English is not my first language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a version using modern JavaScript array functions.

The approach is as follows:

- Determine the digits of the number by converting it to a string (in decimal notation) and putting all characters in an array. This would convert the number 503 to `['5', '0', '3']`.
- Calculate the sum of the digits by first transforming every digit back to a number again (`parseInt`, which assumes decimal notation by default), and then calculating the sum using the [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function.
- Print the number when the sum of its digits is divisible by 8. We check this by seeing if the remainder after division by 8 is 0: `sum % 8 === 0`. This is called [remainder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()), or modulo.

```js
for (let i = 1; i <= 1000; ++i) {
  let digits = i.toString().split(''),
      sum = digits.map((d) => parseInt(d)).reduce((a, v) => a + v);
  if (sum % 8 === 0) {
    console.log(i, 'because', digits.join(' + '), '=', sum, 'is divisible by 8');
  }
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(var i = 1 ; i <= 1000; i++) {
    var digitSum = String(i).split('').reduce((a, b) => +a+(+b));
    if(digitSum % 8 === 0) {
        console.log(i)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you use +a+(+b) instead of simply a + b?

Comment: @parrker9 Because `a` and `b` are strings: `'2' + '1' = '21'`. Adding the plus signs transforms them into numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the math and the code:

```js
for(var i = 0 ; i< 1001; i++) {
  var stringNumber = i.toString();
  var sum = 0;
  for(var j = 0 ; j < stringNumber.length; j++) {
    sum+= parseInt(stringNumber.charAt(j));
  }
  if(sum%8===0) console.log(i);
}
```

Next time, make sure that you show proof of a minimal code solution that you *tried* and did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution:

```js
for(var i = 0 ; i< 1001; i++) {
  var arNum = i.toString().split('');
  var sumNum = arNum.reduce(add, 0);
  if(sumNum%8===0) console.log(i);
}

function add(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}
```